Relativistic Lagrangian for a System of Massive Particles
The standard Lagrangian $L$ written in local coordinates for a free, relativistic particle of mass $m > 0$ is given by
$$L(q, \dot{q}) = -m \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}(q) \dot{q}^\mu \dot{q}^\nu}\tag{1}$$
where I have chosen to use the mostly pluses metric signature. Parameterizing the particle's world line by its proper time $\tau$, the corresponding action $S$ is
$$S[q] = \int_{\tau_1}^{\tau_2} -m \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}(q) \frac{dq^\mu}{d\tau} \frac{dq^\nu}{d\tau}}d\tau.\tag{2}$$
We might consider extending this situation by introducing a (possibly 4-velocity-dependent) external potential $U$ so that
$$S[q] = \int_{\tau_1}^{\tau_2} \bigg[-m \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}(q) \frac{dq^\mu}{d\tau} \frac{dq^\nu}{d\tau}} - U\Big(q, \frac{dq}{d\tau}\Big)\bigg]d\tau.\tag{3}$$
This is all nice and Lorentz-covariant so far. But what happens when we try to introduce multiple particles with masses $m_{(i)} > 0$ (Parentheses are to distinguish labels from indices) and their interaction potentials $$V_{(i, j)}(q_{(i)}, q_{(j)}, \dot{q}_{(i)}, \dot{q}_{(j)})~?\tag{4}$$
Let us assume that the form of the interactions is compatible with special relativity. Perhaps they are mediated by some field whose dynamics are specified by a separate Lagrangian density. What I would like to know is: What is the Lorentz-covariant Lagrangian for this new situation with multiple particles?
The first issue I encounter when considering this problem is what parameter to use in the action. To keep things Lorentz-covariant, we might try something like the proper time. But then which particle's proper time do we use? To avoid singling out any one particle, we might choose to parameterize each world line by its coordinate time. But then this artificially singles out a preferred reference frame.

The multiple time problem is quite annoying and is still not completely solved, even in SR, and now you want to play with GR. But in your integral you could have just used any suitable parameter and obtained correct physics; the problem you are hitting is yet to be the annoying multiple time problem.

One idea would be to try to make the action worldline (WL) reparametrization invariant $$\tau\quad\longrightarrow\quad\tau^{\prime}~=~f(\tau) \tag{A}$$
Here $\tau$ denotes an arbitrary WL parameter that is not necessarily the proper time of some point particle. [OP's action (2) already satisfies this.] Then it doesn't matter which $\tau$ to use.

It is not possible to describe interaction of two or more particles via usual action integral with Lagrangian terms like $V(q_1,\dot{q}_1,q_2,\dot{q}_2)$ integrated over some global time-like parameter, because in relativistic theory, force on particle 1 cannot be a function of position and velocity of the particle 2 at the same "time", irrespective of which frame time it is. In relativistic theory with interaction propagating at speed $c$, particle events can be linked only if they are on the same light cone.
Instead, interaction can be described by action where we integrate over both particle trajectories, and proper weight picks out the other particle event on the light cone. Such action is e.g. the Schwarzschild-Tetrode-Fokker action, see e.g. the article Feynman, Wheeler: Classical Electrodynamics in Terms of Direct Interparticle Action, Rev. Mod. Phys. 21, 425 (1949), pdf: https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.21.425
This solves your question "which particle's proper time do we use?" - all particle proper times are used (or some other parameters, related to particle proper times).
